# How to check if my serial port is not receiving any more data in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to determine whether I am receiving data or not, since every time I run my program I am expecting a different amount of data. Here is my code to illustrate:`

```
List<int> Receiverlist = new List<int>();
 while (There is data from serialPort1 ) {
  serialinput = serialPort1.ReadChar();
  Receiverlist.Add(serialinput);
  }`
```

Do I need to add \0 in the end of my list ?

Comment: if you want to check you've received any data you can capture last date time you received a data and check it with a timer. But if you want do another thing let us to know about what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `BytesToRead` property. It will show you whether data is in the received buffer. If so you can read it with one of the read methods.

In your code example you seem to read char by char

```
List<int> Receiverlist = new List<int>();

while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0) 
{
    string serialinput = serialPort1.ReadChar();
    Receiverlist.Add(serialinput);
}
```

another possibility would be to read the entire buffer and parse the input afterwards:

```
if(serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0) 
{
    string serialinput = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    // parse the input according to your needs
}
```

> Do I need to add \0 in the end of my list ?

It depends on what your purpose is with this char. 
But to get the last element of a list you can just use:

```
int last = Receiverlist.Last();
```

Comment: I will use the list directly to process the data, so I think it could be better read char by char, instead of parsing the data then process it.